# Where does the name "Beelzeboul" come from?

Tags: hebrew, mark

Mark 3:22:<sup>1</sup>

> Καὶ οἱ γραμματεῖς οἱ ἀπὸ Ἱεροσολύμων καταβάντες ἔλεγον ὅτι **Βεελζεβοὺλ** ἔχει καὶ ὅτι ἐν τῷ ἄρχοντι τῶν δαιμονίων ἐκβάλλει τὰ δαιμόνια. ([NA28](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/51/30022/30022/ch/d6e37b3ba85d90d8320abe681ce99cd4/))
>
> And the scribes who came down from Jerusalem were saying, “He is possessed by **Beelzebul**,” and “by the prince of demons he casts out the demons.” ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Mark%203%3A22/))

I’m trying to figure out where the word *Beelzeboul*<sup>2</sup> comes from. It appears to be something like transliterated Hebrew, possibly derived from 2 Kings 1:  בַּעַל  זְבוּב (*baʿal  zĕbûb* — *lord of the flies*<sup>3</sup>), but this is different. The LXX  Βααλ μυῖαν (*Baal muian*) is half-translated, half-transliterated and looks nothing like *Beelzeboul*.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beelzebub) offers that *‘zeboul* might be explained as:

- A slurred pronunciation of *zebûb*
- *Zebel*, a word used to mean "dung" in the Targums
- Hebrew *zebûl* found in 1 Kings 8:13 in the phrase *bêt-zebûl*, "lofty house"

I’m pretty sure this paragraph in HALOT explains at least one theory of the derivation, but I just can’t quite follow it:

[image]

- Is Beelzeboul a term derived from the Hebrew bible, and if so how?
- Are there extra-biblical examples of Beelzeboul used as a synonym for Satan?

---

<sup>**Notes**</sup>


<sup>1. Also found in the parallel stories in Matt 12 and Luke 11.</sup>

<sup>2. I don’t really understand the transliteration without the “o” (unless they’re resorting to the Hebrew - !), so I put it back in. Since the question is not really about the English, I figured nobody would mind.</sup>

<sup>3. Although for some reason this is nearly always transliterated rather than translated in English versions.</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As OP notes, the New Testament's Βεελζεβούλ [Beelzebul] appears to come -- somehow -- from the Hebrew Bible's (Christian Old Testament's) בַּעַל זְבוּב [*baʿal zĕbûb*], "Lord of the flies".<sup>a</sup> Two specific questions are posed:

> 1. Is Beelzeboul a term derived from the Hebrew Bible, and if so how?

The short answer is **yes**, errr, *probably* -- but the "how" takes a bit longer.

As Ted Lewis writes in the *Anchor Bible Dictionary*, having noted the NT occurrences: "Scholars have been fascinated with trying to find an etymology for this preeminent satanic being".<sup>1</sup>

There have been a welter of suggestions.<sup>2</sup> A number of these have had only minimal support, and I won't report these below; there are two which have attracted the most sustained and widespread ... support, if not acceptance:

1. The HB/OT references for *baʿal zĕbûb* are given in the *HALOT* entry cited in the question, but for convenience they are: 2 Kgs 1:2, 3, 6, and 16 -- so [four times in one chapter](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+kings+1%3A2,3,6,16&version=NASB;WLC). And that's it for the HB/OT.

   The translation tradition into Greek (and Syriac) knows both the *-ub* (Aquila) and *-ul* (Symmachus) versions beside the LXX's own Βααλ μυῖαν.<sup>3</sup> When texts from [ancient Ugarit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugarit) were found with a reading of *zbl bʿl*, = "Baal" plus epithet, "Exalted Baal" or the like, then the suggestion seemed almost irresistible that the HB/OT's *zebub* was a denigrating substitution for *zebul* (cf. *HALOT*, sub זְבֻל II, "lofty"). An analogy might be in the substitution of *~boshet* (= "shame") for *~baal* in, e.g., the name "Ishbosheth" (compare [NASB and NRSV at 2 Samuel 2:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20sam%202%3A8&version=NASB;WLC;NRSV)).
2. The second suggestion ignores the *zebub* connection, in preference to finding a solution wholly from the HB/OT's *zebul* references (1 Kgs 8:13; Ps 49:15; Isa 63:15; Hab 3:11). Here, the connection is simply "Lord of Heaven", and the *-ub* version arises by false assimilation to the 2 Kings 1 text.

As I say, there are other explanations, but these two (or variations) are the leading contenders.

> 2. Are there extra-biblical examples of Beelzeboul used as a synonym for Satan?

Only in the ~ούλ form. According to W. Foerster,<sup>4</sup> it is found in Origen, *Contra Celsum*, VIII.25; and Hippolytus, *Refutatio Omnium Haeresium*, VI.34.1; also in the *[Testament of Solomon](http://www.earlyjewishwritings.com/testsolomon.html)* -- although in the latter it might *not* be used of Satan.<sup>5</sup>

**For further reading** see the helpful article by E.C.B. MacLaurin, "[Beelzeboul](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1560470)", *Novum Testamentum* 20/2 (1978): 156-160.

---

*Notes*

<sup>a</sup> <sub>Note that "Baal" (or East Semitic *bēl*) is "lord", not "god". As it happens, Josephus, [*Antiquities*, IX.19](https://archive.org/stream/josephuswithengl06joseuoft#page/12/mode/2up/search/akkaron) has τὸν Ακκαρων θεὸν μυῖαν = "the Fly-God of Akkaron" - see Thackeray's edition (linked) for details.</sub>

1. T.J. Lewis, "Beelzebul", in *[The Anchor Bible Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385193513)*, gen. ed. David Noel Freedman (Doubleday, 1992), vol. 1, pp. 638-40.
2. Most of what follows comes from Lewis, but pared down to essentials. See also W. Herrmann, "[Baal Zebub](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yCkRz5pfxz0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA154#v=onepage&q&f=false)", in *[Dictionary of Deities and Demons in the Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802824919)* ed. by K. van der Toorn *et al* (2nd edn; Brill, 1999), pp. 154-156. There is a good deal of overlap between the two articles.
3. Citations most readily seen in  Frederick Field, *Origenis Hexaplorum...* (2 vols; 1875), [vol. 1, p. 651](https://archive.org/stream/origenhexapla01unknuoft#page/651/mode/1up) (= *ad loc*).
4. W. Foerster, "Βεελζεβούλ", in *[Theological Dictionary of the New Testament](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802822436)*, ed. by G. Kittel (Eedrmans, 1964), vol. 1, pp. 605-6.
5. Frequently - use `CTRL-F` to search *Beelzeboul* in the [online text](http://www.esotericarchives.com/solomon/testamen.htm).